# What is easiest way to assign value to variable from API response in Python (instead of writing response to JSON and assigning it from JSON file)?

Tags: python, api, youtube-api

I have working code in Python (publish only part connected with question):

```
###Here Request and Response from API (Response containing some "id" value)
***
response = request.execute()
print(response)

for item in response["id"]:
  print(item)  #Give me only ID in reponse

json_data = response
for item in json_data["id"]:
    with open("response.json", "w") as outfile:
        outfile.write(str(json_data["id"]))   #write only ID in file "response.json"

with open('response.json', 'r') as f:   #Assign to Variable1 value from 1st line of "response.json"
    Variable1 = f.readline()    

print(Variable1)   #print Variable1 for check
```

`print(response)` from API gives (some value changed for "***"):

```
Loading Credentials From File...
Refreshing Access Token...
{'kind': 'youtube#liveBroadcast', 'etag': '*********', 'id': *********, 'snippet': {'publishedAt': '2022-10-13T10:14:14Z', 'channelId': '*********', 'title': 'Test broadcast', 'description': '', 'thumbnails': {'default': {'url': 'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/*********/default_live.jpg', 'width': 120, 'height': 90}, 'medium': {'url': 'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/*********/mqdefault_live.jpg', 'width': 320, 'height': 180}, 'high': {'url': 'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/*********/hqdefault_live.jpg', 'width': 480, 'height': 360}}, 'scheduledStartTime': '2022-10-13T17:31:00Z', 'scheduledEndTime': '2022-10-13T17:32:00Z', 'isDefaultBroadcast': False, 'liveChatId': '*********'}, 'status': {'lifeCycleStatus': 'created', 'privacyStatus': 'unlisted', 'recordingStatus': 'notRecording', 'madeForKids': False, 'selfDeclaredMadeForKids': False}, 'contentDetails': {'monitorStream': {'enableMonitorStream': True, 'broadcastStreamDelayMs': 0, 'embedHtml': '<iframe width="425" height="344" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/*********?autoplay=1&livemonitor=1" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>'}, 'enableEmbed': True, 'enableDvr': True, 'enableContentEncryption': True, 'startWithSlate': False, 'recordFromStart': True, 'enableClosedCaptions': True, 'closedCaptionsType': 'closedCaptionsHttpPost', 'enableLowLatency': False, 'latencyPreference': 'normal', 'projection': 'rectangular', 'enableAutoStart': False, 'enableAutoStop': False}}
[Finished in 2.0s]
```

Is there any simplier way to assign to `Variable1` value of `id` from response of API in Python language?

Answer (score 0):

You should start with the ['JSON Reponse Content' from Requests documentation](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#json-response-content)

Then you can assign the value of id to your `response_id` variable:

```py
json_response = r.json()
response_id = json_response["id"]
```

Comment: Thanks, for answer, I will try to explore this documantation!